# Bootstrap link button destination

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is absurdly simple, but I was delegated the task of adding a blog to our bootstrap site, and I know virtually nothing about CSS. I decided that what I can do is set up a wordpress blog on a subdomain of our site, so all I need to do in bootstrap is add a clickable link in our header, that goes to blog.ourwebsite.com.

I've just copy and pasted a line of code, adding a button that says "blog" but as you can see, it does nothing, it just adds the actual button to the page. I want it to go to a subdomain of our site. I assume I'd just change the class from page-scroll to something else?

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a class="page-scroll" id="homeButton">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a class="page-scroll" id="featuresButton">FEATURES</a></li>
                <li><a class="page-scroll" id="workButton">HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
                <li><a class="page-scroll" id="teamVisionButton">TEAM VISION</a></li>
                <li><a class="page-scroll" id="teamButton">TEAM</a></li>
                <li><a class="page-scroll" id="blogButton">BLOG</a></li>
                <li><a class="page-scroll" id="contactButton">CONTACT</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div><!-- End navbar menu -->
```

Comment: Shouldn't the link have an `href`attribute? How else will the browser know what to do with your link (not a button btw)?

Comment: where is your `id`? and your anchor tags has no `href`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing your href from the  tag.

```
<li><a class="page-scroll" id="blogButton" href="URL HERE">BLOG</a></li>
```